# Attention type 'block_sparse' is not possible if sequence_length: 458 <= num global tokens:

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am using the pre-trained `google/bigbird-pegasus-large-arxiv` model.

But I receive the following update during the forward pass.

```
Attention type 'block_sparse' is not possible if sequence_length: 458 <= num global tokens: 2 * config.block_size + min. num sliding tokens: 3 * config.block_size + config.num_random_blocks * config.block_size + additional buffer: config.num_random_blocks * config.block_size = 704 with config.block_size = 64, config.num_random_blocks = 3.Changing attention type to 'original_full'...
```

I understand the update and I am aware of benefit of time and memory it saves while using `block_sparse` than `original_full`.

So, how should I go about selecting the suitable `block_size` and  `num_random_blocks` when I know that there is a lot of variation in the sequence length of my inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I end up setting `padding='max_length'` in `tokenizer.encode()`. It will guarantee that the model will always use "block_sparse" attention type.